# My implementation of RandomForestRegressor application to predict soccer goals

Tags: python, performance

I am using RandomForestRegressor to predict a set of soccer matches to predict the number of goals scored for a given match/set of matches is as below:

```
 dte.head()
    
        HomeTeam

    AwayTeam      B365H    B365D    B365A     FTHG    FTAG
--  --------------  ----------  -------  -------  -------   ------  ------
 0  Leeds           Chelsea        4.8      3.9      1.68      nan     nan
 1  Crystal Palace  West Brom      2.28     3        3.4       nan     nan
 2  Everton         Burnley        1.95     3.2      4.2       nan     nan
 3  Fulham          Man City      10.5      5        1.3       nan     nan
 4  Southampton     Brighton       2.9      3.05     2.55      nan     nan

dtr.head()

    HomeTeam        AwayTeam       FTHG    FTAG
--  --------------  -----------  ------  ------
 0  Fulham          Arsenal           0       3
 1  Crystal Palace  Southampton       1       0
 2  Liverpool       Leeds             4       3
 3  West Ham        Newcastle         0       2
 4  West Brom       Leicester         0       3



def encode_features(df_train, df_test):
    features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test

dtr, dte = encode_features(dtr, dte)

dtr_g = dtr.loc[:, dte.columns.intersection(
    ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG', 'B365H', 'B365D', 'B365A'])]
dte_g = dte.loc[:, dte.columns.intersection(
    ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG', 'B365H', 'B365D', 'B365A'])]
dtr_g_h = dtr_g.drop(['FTAG'], axis=1)
dtr_g_a = dtr_g.drop(['FTHG'], axis=1)
dte_g = dte_g.drop(['FTHG', 'FTAG'], axis=1)
dte_g = dte_g.dropna()

# Encoding string features
def encode_features(df_train, df_test):
    features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test

dtr, dte = encode_features(dtr, dte)
# After Encoding

dte_g.head()

      HomeTeam    AwayTeam    B365H    B365D    B365A    Month    Weekend/Weekday
--  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -----------------
 0         271         114     4.8      3.9      1.68        3                  2
 1         134         495     2.28     3        3.4         3                  2
 2         170          88     1.95     3.2      4.2         3                  2
 3         194         297    10.5      5        1.3         3                  2
 4         429          83     2.9      3.05     2.55        3                  1

dtr_g_h.head()

      HomeTeam    AwayTeam    B365H    B365D    B365A    Month    FTHG    Weekend/Weekday
--  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ------  -----------------
 0         194          33     6        4.33     1.53        9       0                  1
 1         134         428     3.1      3.25     2.37        9       1                  1
 2         282         271     1.28     6        9.5         9       4                  1
 3         497         326     2.15     3.4      3.4         9       0                  1
 4         496         273     3.8      3.6      1.95        9       0                  1


dtr_g_a.head()

      HomeTeam    AwayTeam    B365H    B365D    B365A    Month    FTAG    Weekend/Weekday
--  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ------  -----------------
 0         194          33     6        4.33     1.53        9       3                  1
 1         134         428     3.1      3.25     2.37        9       0                  1
 2         282         271     1.28     6        9.5         9       3                  1
 3         497         326     2.15     3.4      3.4         9       2                  1
 4         496         273     3.8      3.6      1.95        9       3                  1

# Predicing Goals

X_g_h = dtr_g_h.drop(['FTHG'], axis=1)
y_g_h = dtr_g_h['FTHG']
X_g_a = dtr_g_a.drop(['FTAG'], axis=1)
y_g_a = dtr_g_a['FTAG']
print("Splitting for Home")
train_X_g_h, val_X_g_h, train_y_g_h, val_y_g_h = train_test_split(X_g_h, y_g_h, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
print("Splitting for away goals")
train_X_g_a, val_X_g_a, train_y_g_a, val_y_a = train_test_split(X_g_a, y_g_a, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
print("Running Random Forest model")
rf_model_on_full_data_g_h = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_model_on_full_data_g_a = RandomForestRegressor()

print("Fitting for home goals")
rf_model_on_full_data_g_h.fit(X_g_h, y_g_h)
rf_model_on_full_data_g_a.fit(X_g_a, y_g_a)

print("Predicting goals for Home Team")
test_preds_h_g = rf_model_on_full_data_g_h.predict(dte_g)

print("Predicting goals for Away Team")
test_preds_a_g = rf_model_on_full_data_g_a.predict(dte_g)


result = pd.DataFrame({
    'League': dte_input.League,
    'Match DateTime': dte_input.DateTime,
    'Home Team': dte_input.HomeTeam,
    'Away Team': dte_input.AwayTeam,
    'Full time Home Goals': test_preds_h_g,
    'Full time Away Goals': test_preds_a_g,
    })

result.head():

|     | League                 | Match DateTime             | Home Team          | Away Team           |   Full time Home Goals |   Full time Away Goals |
|-----|------------------------|----------------------------|--------------------|---------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|   0 | English Premier League | 2021-03-12 23:00:00.000001 | Leeds              | Chelsea             |                   1.23 |               1.84     |
|   1 | English Premier League | 2021-03-12 23:00:00.000001 | Crystal Palace     | West Brom           |                   1.65 |               1.13     |
|   2 | English Premier League | 2021-03-12 23:00:00.000001 | Everton            | Burnley             |                   1.4  |               0.73     |
|   3 | English Premier League | 2021-03-12 23:00:00.000001 | Fulham             | Man City            |                   0.59 |               2.35     |
|   4 | English Premier League | 2021-03-13 23:00:00.000001 | Southampton        | Brighton            |                   1.34 |               1.36     |
|   5 | English Premier League | 2021-03-13 23:00:00.000001 | Leicester          | Sheffield United    |                   1.75 |               0.92     |
|   6 | English Premier League | 2021-03-13 23:00:00.000001 | Arsenal            | Tottenham           |                   1.37 |               1.19     |
```

My queston is predominantly:

1. Am I applying the regression correctly? I am getting an output which (within the understanding of soccer matches and its outcome boundaries) is acceptable to real world output. How it comes together; I am partially aware of it.
2. If I can understand it in layman terms, I am asking the question: 1- Predict Home team goals when two teams are playing based on historical data. 2. Predict the Away team goals in the same manner. But, these are discreet questions which are answered discreetly while the soccer event is not discreete but dynamic.(I can probably word this better definitely) Am I approaching this problem corrctly?
3. Is there any way I can use `.predict` in a manner that I can get the HomeTeam and AwayTeam predictions at the same time? (AFAIK `.predict` can be only used for one variable, not multi variables)

If I apply `GridsearchCV`, the results dont improve (wrt real world comparison) hence there is no value in the processing resources/result tradeoff. Can I improve on this algorithim/apply better `sklearn.predict` options?

Comment: Can I see the full code? Some of the dataframes are not defined...

Comment: I have since changed the code and thus use updated dataframes.. however the question remains same and unanswered. lol. Also, to answer your question and  with CR principles,, I will dig into archives and edit the question to help answer it.